# Проверить одинаковы ли цифры числа

Tags: javascript

```
let num = 333;
let changed = Number(num.toString().split('').sort((a,b)=> a-b).join(''))
let equals = (num == changed) ? true:false
console.log(equals);
```

Вот мое решение, но как сделать через цикл

Comment: Это решение неверное (123). А через цикл - деление на 10 с остатком

Comment: Действительно, а как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Ну если вам таким способом хочется - проверьте на совпадение последней и первой цифры после сортировки, но без превращения в число ( а то 101 пройдёт)

Comment: `new Set(String(num)).size == 1`

Comment: @Ghost Если вы хотите проверить одинаковые числа, тогда зачем вам вообще цикл?  Мы берем число ```321```, там  не одинаковые числа, у числа ```321``` число 3, 2, 1.  Вам достаточно сравнить первое число со вторым и если оно не совпадает, верните  false.